# multiple Value of group of fields in CCK

Tags: 7, entities

I would like to create a form with CCK.

The user should be able to create unlimited number of "people" :

```
M    -  Smith   -   John
Mrs  -  Dave    -   Lily
M    -  John    -   Doe
...
```

So I need a Select (with gender) - textfield (last name) - textfield (first name).

I can not create each field to unlimited it would not be linked.
I have tried field_group, but it does not give me the ability to put multiple value.

What would be the best way to do that ?
I thought about create my own field with those 3 inputs. but it seems way to complicated for the simple thing I need to do. further more I cannot find any good tutorial.

EDIT : I'm using Drupal 7