# Repeating text field on user profile

Tags: 7, entities, users

In the user profiles, I would like to have an education field grouping. In this grouping I'd like to have these text fields.

- Degree: BS/BA, MA/MS, PhD, Post Doc, etc
- University
- Year Graduated
- Area of Study

Now, my users will have multiple degrees and such.

Can I create a "repeating" group of these four fields from 0 to infinity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple Value of group of fields in CCK](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19578/multiple-value-of-group-of-fields-in-cck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) should be a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in Drupal 7, check out the [Field Groups Module](http://drupal.org/project/field_group).

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All
>   fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap
>   their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers
>   like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div
>   wrappers.

If you're on Drupal 6, you want the MultiGroup module, which is a part of the 3.x branch of [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck).